# How to get onclick listener in google docs using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Can you please tell me if there is any way of get onclick listener in google docs using app script? I will have some links in a doc. I want to perform an action if user clicks any of the links.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to run a script based on a user clicking on text.

You may want to look into creating [custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) or [dialogs and sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs). These approaches let you add buttons *around* the document that trigger scripts.